# How can i programmatically add springs and struts to subviews of an NSView

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

Basically I have an NSView subclass, and it generates a whole bunch of subviews programmatically.  I want them to arrange in a grid manner with one point between each of them.

I know I can do this in IB by using springs and struts is there a way to add the springs and struts programmatically?

Assume that you can get any given subview from its x, y from the top left starting with 1.
Like this

```
_____________________
|      |      |      |
| 1, 1 | 2, 1 | 3, 1 |
|______|______|______|
|      |      |      |
| 1, 2 | 2, 2 | 3, 2 |
|______|______|______|
|      |      |      |
| 1, 3 | 2, 3 | 3, 3 |
|______|______|______|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually do this with springs and struts. When using springs and struts, the relationship is only between a view frame and its superview bounds, not with its neighbors.

Anyway, what you think of as springs and struts is the `autoresizingMask` of the view. You can set it using `-setAutoresizingMask:`.

Comment: How would i use autoresizing masks to make what I want? How do they work?

Comment: As I say, I don't believe you can do what you want with autoresizing masks. The mask indicates whether the margin between an edge of the view and the corresponding edge of its superview can grow or shrink as the superview grows and shrinks and, similarly, whether the view's width or height can grow. So, in the horizontal direction there's the margin on the left, the width, and the margin on the right. The change in size of the superview is distributed among however many of those are allowed to change. Similarly in the vertical direction.